# Ruby on rail 3.1 not working with paperclip 3.2.0 vs 3.0.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm using paperclip on a project that works perfectly with paperclip 3.0.3 but totally bug with paperclip 3.2.0. With 3.0.3 it crop the image and add watermarks, with 3.2.0 it loop while processing the first command of each image and do it again and again until it crash.

the code found below come mostly from the Railcast about paperclip and other code i found here on stackoverflow. I though it might interest people to see a working (with paperclip 3.0.3) version with all this integrated.

here is the code of the model

```
require 'paperclip_processors/watermark'
require 'paperclip_processors/cropper'

class Imageblock < ActiveRecord::Base

   belongs_to :block

   attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h, :old_size_width, :old_size_height

   validates_presence_of :size_width, :size_height, :photo

   validates_format_of :description, :with => /\A[^"]+\z/, :message => "No quotes allowed"

   has_attached_file :photo, :styles => lambda { |attachment| 
       image = attachment.instance
       dimensions = "#{image.size_width}x#{image.size_height}#"
       { 
          :small => {:geometry => "100x100#"},
          :custom => {:geometry => dimensions, :processors => [:cropper] },
          :large => {:geometry => "500x500>"},
          :display =>{:geometry => "1000x1000>", :watermark_path => "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/monogram.png", :processors => [:watermark]},
          :retina =>{:geometry => "2000x2000>", :watermark_path => "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/monogram.png", :processors => [:watermark]} 
       }
   }, :dependant => :destroy,  :url => "/art/photo/:id/:style/:basename.:extension", :path => ":rails_root/public/art/photo/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

   after_update :reprocess_photo, :if => :cropping?

   def cropping?
       !crop_x.blank? && !crop_y.blank? && !crop_w.blank? && !crop_h.blank?
   end

   def photo_geometry(style = :original)
       @geometry ||= {}
       @geometry[style] ||= Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(photo.path(style))
   end

   private

   def reprocess_photo
       photo.reprocess!
   end

 end
```

here is the code of the cropper processor

```
module Paperclip
class Cropper < Thumbnail
   def transformation_command
      if crop_command
         crop_command + super.join(' ').sub(/ -crop \S+/, '').split(' ') # super returns     an array like this: ["-resize", "100x", "-crop", "100x100+0+0", "+repage"]
      else
        super
      end
    end

    def crop_command
       target = @attachment.instance
       if target.cropping?
          ["-crop", "#{target.crop_w}x#{target.crop_h}+#{target.crop_x}+#{target.crop_y}"]
       end
    end
  end
end
```

the code of the watermark is very long and was found in stackoverflow

```
module Paperclip
class Watermark < Processor
 # Handles watermarking of images that are uploaded.
   attr_accessor :current_geometry, :target_geometry, :format, :whiny, :convert_options, :watermark_path, :overlay, :position

   def initialize file, options = {}, attachment = nil
      super
      geometry          = options[:geometry]
      @file             = file
      @crop             = geometry[-1,1] == '#'
      @target_geometry  = Geometry.parse geometry
      @current_geometry = Geometry.from_file @file
      @convert_options  = options[:convert_options]
      @whiny            = options[:whiny].nil? ? true : options[:whiny]
      @format           = options[:format]
      @watermark_path   = options[:watermark_path]
      @position         = options[:position].nil? ? "SouthEast" : options[:position]
      @overlay          = options[:overlay].nil? ? true : false
      @current_format   = File.extname(@file.path)
      @basename         = File.basename(@file.path, @current_format)
    end

    # TODO: extend watermark

    # Returns true if the +target_geometry+ is meant to crop.
     def crop?
       @crop
     end

     # Returns true if the image is meant to make use of additional convert options.
     def convert_options?
       not @convert_options.blank?
     end

     # Performs the conversion of the +file+ into a watermark. Returns the Tempfile
     # that contains the new image.
     def make
       dst = Tempfile.new([@basename, @format].compact.join("."))
       dst.binmode

       command = "convert"
       params = [fromfile]
       params += transformation_command
       params << tofile(dst)
       begin
         success = Paperclip.run(command, params.flatten.compact.collect{|e| "'#{e}'"}.join(" "))
         rescue PaperclipCommandLineError
         raise PaperclipError, "There was an error resizing and cropping #{@basename}" if @whiny
       end

       if watermark_path
         command = "composite"
         params = %W[-gravity #{@position} #{watermark_path} #{tofile(dst)}]
         params << tofile(dst)
         begin
           success = Paperclip.run(command, params.flatten.compact.collect{|e| "'#{e}'"}.join(" "))
         rescue 
           raise PaperclipError, "There was an error processing the watermark for #{@basename}" if @whiny
         end
       end

       dst
     end

     def fromfile
       File.expand_path(@file.path)
     end

     def tofile(destination)
       File.expand_path(destination.path)
     end

     def transformation_command
       scale, crop = @current_geometry.transformation_to(@target_geometry, crop?)
       trans = %W[-resize #{scale}]
       trans += %W[-crop #{crop} +repage] if crop
       trans << convert_options if convert_options?
       trans
     end
  end
end
```

if anybody have idea why is it not working with paperclip 3.2.0, i can't find any help on the web about this bug.

cheers

Comment: Time to upgrade to 3.2 :D or even 4.0

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: no, i actually don't have ressources to update the application from 3.1.1 to 3.2.x and see if the problem is solved (if paperclip 3.2.x is for rails 3.2.x)

Answer (score 0):

look at
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/866
it should have been fixed.

**update**

your code will run in a deep stack level error. it is caused through after_update filter callback and changes in paperclip (look at issue 866). you have to move the reprocess! call from the model to the controller#update

```
def update
  if @asset.save
    if params[:asset][:crop_x] 
      @asset.attach.reprocess!
    end
    redirect_to ..
```

Comment: it wasnt fixed.for rails 3.2.8 paperclip 3.3.1 # update above